SSH Agent Forwarding option with YubiKey Not Working on Ubuntu Gnome 24.04
ssh to server and when running ssh-add -l 'The agent has no identities.'. However running the same command on my local machine yields the same response, so im not sure what thats about either. But the pkcs provider is specified in ~/.ssh/config. And ssh debug show messages of pkcs and agent forwarding.
config:
Host *
        PKCS11Provider /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opensc-pkcs11.so

shell:
athena@athena-T450:~$ ssh-add -l
The agent has no identities.
athena@athena-T450:~$ ssh -A zeus@192.168.50.11 -vvv
OpenSSH_9.6p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu13.5, OpenSSL 3.0.13 30 Jan 2024
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/athena/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/athena/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 192.168.50.11 is address
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/home/athena/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/home/athena/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug3: channel_clear_timeouts: clearing
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.50.11 [192.168.50.11] port 22.
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IP_TOS 0x10
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: provider /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opensc-pkcs11.so: manufacturerID <OpenSC Project> cryptokiVersion 2.20 libraryDescription <OpenSC smartcard framework> libraryVersion 0.25
debug1: provider /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opensc-pkcs11.so slot 0: label <SSH> manufacturerID <piv_II> model <PKCS#15 emulated> serial <2c7810b3ba9899b3> flags 0x40d
debug2: pkcs11_fetch_keys: provider /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opensc-pkcs11.so slot 0: RSA SHA256:lbD3GbfrFp6CTmz4fCbgkTQ9XrylzTMePOeoFUGDRV0
debug1: have 1 keys
debug2: pkcs11_fetch_certs: provider /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opensc-pkcs11.so slot 0: RSA SHA256:lbD3GbfrFp6CTmz4fCbgkTQ9XrylzTMePOeoFUGDRV0
debug2: pkcs11_fetch_certs: key already included
debug1: pkcs11_k11_free: parent 0x5dbbaaac1f80 ptr 0x5dbbaaac18c0 idx 1
debug1: pkcs11_provider_unref: provider "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opensc-pkcs11.so" refcount 2
debug1: identity file /home/athena/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/athena/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/athena/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/athena/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/athena/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/athena/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/athena/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/athena/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/athena/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/athena/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/athena/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/athena/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/athena/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/athena/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_9.6p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu13.5
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_9.6p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu13.5
debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_9.6p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu13.5 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.50.11:22 as 'zeus'
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ED25519 in file /home/athena/.ssh/known_hosts:18
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /home/athena/.ssh/known_hosts:19
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/athena/.ssh/known_hosts:20
debug3: load_hostkeys_file: loaded 3 keys from 192.168.50.11
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/athena/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: have matching best-preference key type ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com, using HostkeyAlgorithms verbatim
debug1: pkcs11_k11_free: parent 0x5dbbaaac1f80 ptr (nil) idx 1
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com,curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,ext-info-c,kex-strict-c-v00@openssh.com
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com,curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,ext-info-s,kex-strict-s-v00@openssh.com
debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug3: kex_choose_conf: will use strict KEX ordering
debug1: kex: algorithm: sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:r4r/DfHEfj6cNhAcK1572xOyzTwDUgQfzGuJITMeqRw
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ED25519 in file /home/athena/.ssh/known_hosts:18
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /home/athena/.ssh/known_hosts:19
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/athena/.ssh/known_hosts:20
debug3: load_hostkeys_file: loaded 3 keys from 192.168.50.11
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/athena/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host '192.168.50.11' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/athena/.ssh/known_hosts:18
debug1: pkcs11_k11_free: parent 0x5dbbaaac1f80 ptr (nil) idx 1
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug1: ssh_packet_send2_wrapped: resetting send seqnr 3
debug2: ssh_set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: Sending SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO
debug3: send packet: type 7
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: ssh_packet_read_poll2: resetting read seqnr 3
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: ssh_set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug3: kex_input_ext_info: extension server-sig-algs
debug1: kex_ext_info_client_parse: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256>
debug3: kex_input_ext_info: extension publickey-hostbound@openssh.com
debug1: kex_ext_info_check_ver: publickey-hostbound@openssh.com=<0>
debug3: kex_input_ext_info: extension ping@openssh.com
debug1: kex_ext_info_check_ver: ping@openssh.com=<0>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug3: kex_input_ext_info: extension server-sig-algs
debug1: kex_ext_info_client_parse: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256>
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug3: ssh_get_authentication_socket_path: path '/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh'
debug1: get_agent_identities: bound agent to hostkey
debug1: get_agent_identities: ssh_fetch_identitylist: agent contains no identities
debug1: Will attempt key: PIV AUTH pubkey RSA SHA256:lbD3GbfrFp6CTmz4fCbgkTQ9XrylzTMePOeoFUGDRV0 token
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/athena/.ssh/id_rsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/athena/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/athena/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/athena/.ssh/id_ed25519 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/athena/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/athena/.ssh/id_xmss 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/athena/.ssh/id_dsa 
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug1: Offering public key: PIV AUTH pubkey RSA SHA256:lbD3GbfrFp6CTmz4fCbgkTQ9XrylzTMePOeoFUGDRV0 token
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug1: Server accepts key: PIV AUTH pubkey RSA SHA256:lbD3GbfrFp6CTmz4fCbgkTQ9XrylzTMePOeoFUGDRV0 token
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: using publickey-hostbound-v00@openssh.com with RSA SHA256:lbD3GbfrFp6CTmz4fCbgkTQ9XrylzTMePOeoFUGDRV0
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: signing using rsa-sha2-512 SHA256:lbD3GbfrFp6CTmz4fCbgkTQ9XrylzTMePOeoFUGDRV0
Enter PIN for 'SSH': 
debug1: pkcs11_check_obj_bool_attrib: provider "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opensc-pkcs11.so" slot 0 object 103060603604544: attrib 514 = 0
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug1: pkcs11_k11_free: parent 0x5dbbaaac1f80 ptr (nil) idx 1
debug3: receive packet: type 52
debug1: pkcs11_k11_free: parent 0x5dbbaaab2050 ptr 0x5dbbaaab5670 idx 1
debug1: pkcs11_provider_unref: provider "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opensc-pkcs11.so" refcount 2
Authenticated to 192.168.50.11 ([192.168.50.11]:22) using "publickey".
debug1: check provider "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opensc-pkcs11.so"
debug1: pkcs11_provider_finalize: provider "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opensc-pkcs11.so" refcount 1 valid 1
debug1: pkcs11_provider_unref: provider "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opensc-pkcs11.so" refcount 1
debug1: channel 0: new session [client-session] (inactive timeout: 0)
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: filesystem
debug3: client_repledge: enter
debug3: receive packet: type 80
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug3: client_input_hostkeys: received RSA key SHA256:tc8m2xpYA/+yqRQhXXH1zgWUJEnVE0kM3hWqayKAw3s
debug3: client_input_hostkeys: received ECDSA key SHA256:4oyllKPfdZXzYGqbjXiu7DpqCnlD3HKVtUG4WudEnL0
debug3: client_input_hostkeys: received ED25519 key SHA256:r4r/DfHEfj6cNhAcK1572xOyzTwDUgQfzGuJITMeqRw
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: searching /home/athena/.ssh/known_hosts for 192.168.50.11 / (none)
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/athena/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug1: pkcs11_k11_free: parent 0x5dbbaaab2ba0 ptr (nil) idx 1
debug1: pkcs11_k11_free: parent 0x5dbbaaab2ba0 ptr (nil) idx 1
debug1: pkcs11_k11_free: parent 0x5dbbaaab2ba0 ptr (nil) idx 1
debug1: pkcs11_k11_free: parent 0x5dbbaaab2ba0 ptr (nil) idx 1
debug1: pkcs11_k11_free: parent 0x5dbbaaab2ba0 ptr (nil) idx 1
debug3: hostkeys_find: found ssh-ed25519 key at /home/athena/.ssh/known_hosts:18
debug3: hostkeys_find: found ssh-rsa key at /home/athena/.ssh/known_hosts:19
debug1: pkcs11_k11_free: parent 0x5dbbaaab2ba0 ptr (nil) idx 1
debug3: hostkeys_find: found ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 key at /home/athena/.ssh/known_hosts:20
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: searching /home/athena/.ssh/known_hosts2 for 192.168.50.11 / (none)
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: hostkeys file /home/athena/.ssh/known_hosts2 does not exist
debug3: client_input_hostkeys: 3 server keys: 0 new, 3 retained, 0 incomplete match. 0 to remove
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: no new or deprecated keys from server
debug1: pkcs11_k11_free: parent 0x5dbbaaaac1a0 ptr (nil) idx 1
debug3: client_repledge: enter
debug3: receive packet: type 4
debug1: Remote: /home/zeus/.ssh/authorized_keys:2: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
debug3: receive packet: type 4
debug1: Remote: /home/zeus/.ssh/authorized_keys:2: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
debug3: receive packet: type 91
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback start
debug3: ssh_get_authentication_socket_path: path '/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh'
debug1: Requesting authentication agent forwarding.
debug2: channel 0: request auth-agent-req@openssh.com confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IP_TOS 0x10
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug1: Sending environment.
debug3: Ignored env SHELL
debug3: Ignored env SESSION_MANAGER
debug3: Ignored env QT_ACCESSIBILITY
debug3: Ignored env COLORTERM
debug3: Ignored env XDG_CONFIG_DIRS
debug3: Ignored env XDG_MENU_PREFIX
debug3: Ignored env GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID
debug3: Ignored env GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL
debug3: Ignored env GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE
debug3: Ignored env SSH_AUTH_SOCK
debug3: Ignored env MEMORY_PRESSURE_WRITE
debug3: Ignored env XMODIFIERS
debug3: Ignored env DESKTOP_SESSION
debug3: Ignored env GTK_MODULES
debug3: Ignored env PWD
debug3: Ignored env LOGNAME
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_TYPE
debug3: Ignored env SYSTEMD_EXEC_PID
debug3: Ignored env XAUTHORITY
debug3: Ignored env HOME
debug3: Ignored env USERNAME
debug3: Ignored env IM_CONFIG_PHASE
debug1: channel 0: setting env LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug3: Ignored env LS_COLORS
debug3: Ignored env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP
debug3: Ignored env MEMORY_PRESSURE_WATCH
debug3: Ignored env VTE_VERSION
debug3: Ignored env WAYLAND_DISPLAY
debug3: Ignored env GNOME_TERMINAL_SCREEN
debug3: Ignored env GNOME_SETUP_DISPLAY
debug3: Ignored env LESSCLOSE
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_CLASS
debug3: Ignored env TERM
debug3: Ignored env LESSOPEN
debug3: Ignored env USER
debug3: Ignored env GNOME_TERMINAL_SERVICE
debug3: Ignored env DISPLAY
debug3: Ignored env SHLVL
debug3: Ignored env GSM_SKIP_SSH_AGENT_WORKAROUND
debug3: Ignored env QT_IM_MODULE
debug3: Ignored env XDG_RUNTIME_DIR
debug3: Ignored env DEBUGINFOD_URLS
debug3: Ignored env XDG_DATA_DIRS
debug3: Ignored env PATH
debug3: Ignored env GDMSESSION
debug3: Ignored env DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
debug3: Ignored env _
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug3: client_repledge: enter
debug1: pledge: agent
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0

zeus@ansible:~$ ssh-add -l
debug3: receive packet: type 90
debug1: client_input_channel_open: ctype auth-agent@openssh.com rchan 2 win 65536 max 16384
debug3: ssh_get_authentication_socket_path: path '/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh'
debug1: client_request_agent: bound agent to hostkey
debug2: fd 11 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 11 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 1: new agent-connection [authentication agent connection] (inactive timeout: 0)
debug1: confirm auth-agent@openssh.com
debug3: send packet: type 91
debug3: receive packet: type 96
debug2: channel 1: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 1: output open -> drain
debug2: channel 1: obuf empty
debug2: chan_shutdown_write: channel 1: (i0 o1 sock 11 wfd 11 efd -1 [closed])
debug2: channel 1: output drain -> closed
debug1: channel 1: FORCE input drain
debug2: channel 1: ibuf empty
debug2: channel 1: send eof
debug3: send packet: type 96
debug2: channel 1: input drain -> closed
debug2: channel 1: send close
debug3: send packet: type 97
The agent has no identities.
zeus@ansible:~$ debug3: channel 1: will not send data after close
debug3: channel 1: will not send data after close
debug3: channel 1: will not send data after close
debug3: receive packet: type 97
debug2: channel 1: rcvd close
debug3: channel 1: will not send data after close
debug2: channel 1: is dead
debug2: channel 1: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 1: free: authentication agent connection, nchannels 2
debug3: channel 1: status: The following connections are open:
  #0 client-session (t4 [session] r0 i0/0 o0/0 e[write]/0 fd 8/9/10 sock -1 cc -1 io 0x01/0x00)
  #1 authentication agent connection (t4 [agent-connection] r2 i3/0 o3/0 e[closed]/0 fd 11/11/-1 sock 11 cc -1 io 0x00/0x00)


debug1: Requesting authentication agent forwarding.

I kind of stumbled on a workaround but I dont understand why its neccessary. Is there some problem with Gnome Keyring/ssh-agent?
athena@athena-T450:~$ echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK
/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh
athena@athena-T450:~$ lsof /run/user/1000/keyring/ssh
COMMAND    PID   USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF  NODE NAME
gnome-key 2726 athena   13u  unix 0x0000000000000000      0t0 21875 /run/user/1000/keyring/ssh type=STREAM (LISTEN)
athena@athena-T450:~$ ps aux | grep ssh-agent
athena      2907  0.0  0.0 162652  6912 ?        Ssl  19:40   0:00 /usr/libexec/gcr-ssh-agent --base-dir /run/user/1000/gcr
athena      6216  0.0  0.0   8432  5888 ?        S    19:49   0:00 /usr/bin/ssh-agent -D -a /run/user/1000/keyring/.ssh
athena      8816  0.0  0.0  17944  2304 pts/1    S+   20:20   0:00 grep --color=auto ssh-agent
athena@athena-T450:~$ eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
Agent pid 8827
athena@athena-T450:~$ ssh-add -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opensc-pkcs11.so
Enter passphrase for PKCS#11: 
Card added: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opensc-pkcs11.so
athena@athena-T450:~$ ssh-add -l
2048 SHA256:lbD3GbfrFp6CTmz4fCbgkTQ9XrylzTMePOeoFUGDRV0 PIV AUTH pubkey (RSA)
athena@athena-T450:~$ echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK
/tmp/ssh-vew7rUAaYWlL/agent.8826
athena@athena-T450:~$ ssh -A zeus@192.168.50.11

zeus@ansible:~$ ssh-add -l
2048 SHA256:lbD3GbfrFp6CTmz4fCbgkTQ9XrylzTMePOeoFUGDRV0 PIV AUTH pubkey (RSA)

